# Count the pixel change in each row

Tags: python, image, image-processing, pixel, image-segmentation

i want to count the pixel changes in each row of an image( which means for any change from black to white or from white to black ),
like the picture bellow:
[Example of letter A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKnzv.png)

i wrote this code, but the second part is wrong :

```
change = [0 for k in range(test.shape[0])]
total = []
for x in range(test.shape[0]-1):
    change[x]=0
    for y in range(test.shape[1]-1):
        if test[x,y+1] != test[x,y]:
            change[x] = change[x] + 1
        elif test[x+1,y+1] != test[x+1, y]:
                change[x] = change[x] + 1

    total.append(change[x])
```

Comment: You want to get the change count per row?

Comment: @Mike67 yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

For counting changes on a row, just compare each pixel to the next pixel on the same row.

In your code, just remove the `elif`.

```
change = [0 for k in range(test.shape[0])]  # changes per row
total = []
for x in range(test.shape[0]):  # each row
    change[x]=0   # not needed
    for y in range(test.shape[1]-1):  # each column
        if test[x,y+1] != test[x,y]:
            change[x] = change[x] + 1
    #    elif test[x+1,y+1] != test[x+1, y]:   # not needed
    #            change[x] = change[x] + 1     # not needed

    total.append(change[x])
```

Comment: but if ou check the photo, my code can not get the number 3 intersections

Answer (score 0):

You can try use Numpy:

```
out=np.sum(np.absolute(np.diff(np.double(img), axis=1))/255.0, axis=1)
```

Comment: yes, i liked what you did, but it can't detect the number 3 ( as you see in the picture)